# Why is there an error when I try to run my secret token

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from replit import db
client = discord.Client()
yes = True
def get_pic():
  cattoURL = requests.api.get("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search").json()[0]['url']
  print(cattoURL)
def get_fact():
  catFact = requests.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact?max_length=140")
  json_data = json.loads(catFact.text)
  return json_data['fact']
print(get_fact())                               
fact = get_fact()
catResponse = ["Heres a catto for you :D","Omg! A wild catto popped up.", "Imagine liking dogs...","Hope you brought pizza"]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
     return

  if message.content.startswith('-catto') or message.content.startswith('-Catto'): 

   await message.channel.send(random.choice(catResponse))
   
   await message.channel.send(content=requests.api.get("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search").json()[0]['url'])
  if message.content.startswith('-fact'):
    fact = get_fact()
    await message.channel.send(fact)
```

The error is this line because when I remove it, theres no error message.

```
client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

> > File "main.py", line 37, in 
> > client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
> > File "/home/runner/Catto-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
> > line 723, in run
> > return future.result()
> > File "/home/runner/Catto-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
> > line 702, in runner
> > await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
> > File "/home/runner/Catto-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
> > line 665, in start
> > await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
> > File "/home/runner/Catto-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
> > line 511, in login
> > await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
> > File "/home/runner/Catto-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py",
> > line 300, in static_login
> > data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
> > File "/home/runner/Catto-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py",
> > line 216, in request
> > raise HTTPException(r, data)
> > discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): 
> >   
> >      
> >      
> >   
> >
> > Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access
>
> ```
> <script>
> (function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var
> ```
>
> e=function(a){var
> c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new
> XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback
> clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
> b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in
> a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
>
> ```
> <script defer src="https://performance.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
> <script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js'></script></head>
> <body>
>   <div id="cf-wrapper">
>     <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable
> ```
>
> cookies.
>
>
>
> Error
> 1015
>
> Ray ID:
> 7291ca361e385ffe •
> 2022-07-11 13:12:17
> UTC
> You are being rate limited
>
> ```
>       <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
>           <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
>             <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What
> ```
>
> happened?
>
> The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.
>
> ```
>           </div>
>
>           
>       </section>
>
>       <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
>     <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
>         Was this page helpful?
>         <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes"
> ```
>
> type="button">Yes
> No
>
>
> Thank you for your feedback!
>
> ```
>       <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0
> ```
>
> border-t border-gray-300">
>
> Cloudflare Ray ID: 7291ca361e385ffe
> •
>
> Your IP:
> Click to reveal
> 35.199.151.82
> •
>
> Performance & security by Cloudflare
>
> ```
>   </p>
>   <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in
> ```
>
> b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var
> a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();
>
> ```
>     </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
>   </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->
>
>   <script>
>   window._cf_translation = {};
>   
>   
> </script>
>
> <script>(function(){window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'7291ca361e385ffe',m:'pUD3DCMtKe1ELGN4iMWaJA_q2wfStb8x1S_EQwqDlPc-1657545137-0-AZfax1Pyr9/O8g9n4WSZTPUQwu7tTIW2B6xw7fseyHw0KzhRdMlbfzcjaO8Ap6NAGBxTZbWT9dsFUe/B9ggUTPUUcBI3JjirVljvXBmUzb2DfSeVyxXNkttjGTX5Le/nn1YJzprLHDelZejW6rDIDKE=',s:[0xfd9affa54e,0xbdccf9731b],}})();</script></body>
> </html
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IP has been temporarily blocked from accessing Discord's API. This typically only lasts around an hour or 24 hours, depending on why you are rate limited.

Repl.it is notoriously known for its hosted Discord bots being disrupted continuously due to its shared hosting system. This rate limit is caused mainly due to someone else on your shared IP having abused the API, whether maliciously or accidentally. You don't need to worry, it's only temporary.